# AngularJS Failed to Load Resourse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following along with an AngularJS class, specifically the AngularJS Fundamentals class, on PluralSight and am creating a demo app using AngularJS. I've followed along perfectly and believe that I've done everything right, but for some reason, my variable isn't being printed to the screen using my controller. I'm getting an error in my console that says "failed to load resource EventController.js 404." How do I fix this?

Here's my `EventDetails.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Event Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        {{event.date}}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then here's my `EventController.js`:

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
function EventController($scope) {

    $scope.event = {
        name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
        date: '5/17/2018',
        time: '11:02 am'
    }
}
```

);

There are the only two things that we've created so far and I'm really confused as to where I messed up. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's my file structure: [image]

Comment: error 404 means it can't find the file. Can you show what your root folder looks like?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey updated, thanks

Comment: @Lex that's what I tried first but it didn't change anything, still got all of the same errors

Comment: are you launching it from a local server?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that removing the '/' at the beginning of all of my script source files allows them to load correctly